# Using different values in find method based on boolean value - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a React component which accepts 3 props:

- code (can be country or currency code)
- currencyCode (boolean)
- countryCode (boolean)

And makes use of a flagsList like so:

```
type CountryEntry = {
  currencyCode?: string,
  countryCode?: string,
  countryLabel: string,
  flagComponent: JSX.Element,
};

export const flagsList: CountryEntry[] = 
  {
    currencyCode: "AED",
    countryCode: "AE",
    countryLabel: "United Arab Emirates (the)",
    flagComponent: UnitedArabEmirates,
  },
  {
    currencyCode: "AFN",
    countryCode: "AF",
    countryLabel: "Afghanistan",
    flagComponent: Afghanistan,
  },
];
```

What I am trying to do is:

- when currencyCode is `true` - search the flagsList by `currencyCode`, and
- when countryCode is `true` search the flagsList by `countryCode`

whilst maintaining the fallback for each if a code cannot be found (`StyledIcon`)

```
const CountryFlag = ({ code, currencyCode, countryCode }: Props) => {
  const countryEntry = flagsList.find(
    (f) => f.currencyCode === currencyCode
  );

  if (!countryEntry) {
    return <StyledIcon name={"countryFallback"} />;
  } else {
    const FlagComponent = countryEntry.flagComponent;

    return (
      <StyledImageWrapper className={className}>
        <FlagComponent />
      </StyledImageWrapper>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: What happens when both `currencyCode` and `countryCode` are true?

Comment: they never can.

Comment: consider passing a single boolean value, e.g. `isCurrency`, when `true` it would treat `code` is currency, when `false` as country code

Comment: I think having a `CodeType` enum with calues `currency` and `country` would be clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a string union or enum instead of multiple booleans.

```
type CountryFlagProps = {
  keyCode: string;
  keyType: "currencyCode" | "countryCode";
};

const CountryFlag = ({ keyCode, keyType }: CountryFlagProps) => {
  const countryEntry = flagsList.find((f) => f[keyType] === keyCode);

  if (countryEntry) {
    return countryEntry.flagComponent
  }

  // Choose your fallback
  return <Flag country="UK" />;
};
```

[image: Edit crazy-parm-hex0l]

---

If you know all of your codes in advance you can be more restrictive and consumers will get better intellisense when using `<CountryFlag />`

```
type CurrencyCode = "AED" | "AFN";
type CountryCode = "AE" | "AF";

type CountryEntry = {
  currencyCode?: CurrencyCode;
  countryCode?: CountryCode;
  countryLabel: string;
  flagComponent: JSX.Element;
};

const flagsList: Array<CountryEntry> = [
  {
    currencyCode: "AED",
    countryCode: "AE",
    countryLabel: "United Arab Emirates (the)",
    flagComponent: <Flag country="AE" />
  },
  {
    currencyCode: "AFN",
    countryCode: "AF",
    countryLabel: "Afghanistan",
    flagComponent: <Flag country="AF" />
  }
];

type CountryFlagProps = {
  keyCode: CurrencyCode | CountryCode;
  keyType: "currencyCode" | "countryCode";
};

const CountryFlag = ({ keyCode, keyType }: CountryFlagProps) => {
  const countryEntry = flagsList.find((f) => f[keyType] === keyCode);

  if (countryEntry) {
    return countryEntry.flagComponent;
  }

  return <Flag country="UK" />;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <CountryFlag keyCode="AF" keyType="countryCode" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit amazing-ardinghelli-ocuk4]